# How are duplicate packets handled at the Data Link Layer?

Tags: wireless, mac-address, lan, layer2, osi

Reading up about the data link layer I found that the **logical link control sublayer** uses **sequence numbers** to find duplicate <strike>packet</strike> frame transmissions.

I understood the sequence number game with respect to *one transmitter* and *receiver* but ***how does it work with multiple transmitters and a single receiver?*** Does the receiver need to **maintain a table with MAC address and the next sequence number**?

Or the duplicate <strike>frame</strike> **"data" (or whatever it is called at that layer)** detection is done at a higher layer?

Comment: Where did you read that logical link control sublayer uses sequence numbers?

Comment: IEEE 802.2 (LLC) type 2 is connection oriented and does use sequence numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connection-oriented protocols are not used in "one transmitter, many receivers" scenarios, because of exactly the problem you mention.  This is true not only of 802.2 Type 2, but also for IP multicast, which only uses UDP, not TCP.

Practically speaking, 802.2 type 2 is obsolete -- You would be hard pressed to find it in use anywhere.

Comment: So you mean to say that the duplicate detection is done at higher layers like TCP? Then how do sliding window techniques detect duplicate frames at the link layer?

Comment: Sliding window doesn't detect duplicate frames only duplicate segments.

Comment: Sliding window doesn't detect duplicate frames/packets.  It is used to make transmissions more efficient by not requiring every frame to be acknowledged individually.  AFAIK, its not used with type 2.

Comment: There is no reliability control for duplicate frames, lost frames etc. on layer 2. All of this is handled by upper layer protocol.

Comment: HDLC does provide for reliable transmission on a point to point link through sequence numbers and ACKs (this includes detecting duplicates), I don't know if it's totally obsolete or still alive somehow.

Comment: @JeanPierre Yes.  In fact, 802.2 was derived from HDLC.